# Проблема с внедрением PdfView в макет

Tags: java, android

некорректно работает модуль [Ссылка на модуль](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

[image: Макет фрагмента]

[image: Макет контейнера]

Так я загружаю документ

```
mPDFView.fromAsset("russian_pronouns_en.pdf").load();
```

Отображаться не хочет, а в стандартном LinearLayout работает, нужна помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте Ваш код в вопрос в виде текста, а не изображения. [**Почему это нужно**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не поставили orientation в linearLayout

Comment: Исправил, не помогло